# How to make multi column tables?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot-table

I am struggling with getting one summary table from the dataframe.

I have a dataframe like below. There 3 dimensions(year, brand, category) and 3 measures(price1, price2, price).

[image]

What I want the output from this dataframe is like this.
[image]

I barely could get the similar result by running the pandas code like below to get this.

```
df.pivot_table (index = 'year'
, values=['price1', 'price2', 'profits']
, columns=['brand', category']
, aggfunc={'price1':'mean', 'price2':'mean', 'profits':'sum'}
)
```

But it gives me the result like this.
[image]

How can I revise the code in python?

Thanks.